# There exists no function $f$ such that $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$ and $f(1/n) = |1/n^3|$ for any $n \in \mathbb Z\backslash \{0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, analyticity

Can anyone confirm that this proof is correct? I don't see any reason for it to be incorrect, but I feel like I may be missing something.

**Theorem:**

> There exists no function $f$ such that $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$ and $f(1/n) = |1/n^3|$ for any $n \in \mathbb Z\backslash \{0\}$.

**Proof:**

> In order to prove this, we will do so by contradiction. Consider the function $f$ described above. Since $0$ is an accumulation point for $S = \{1/n\ |\ 0 < n \in \mathbb Z\backslash \{0\}\}$ and $f(s) = s^3$ for all $s \in S$, we know that $f(z) = z^3$ in the positive half of the complex plane. Since $0$ is an accumulation point for $S^- = \{1/n\ |\ 0 > n \in \mathbb Z\backslash \{0\}\}$ and $f(s) = -s^3$ for all $s \in S^-$, we know that $f(z) = -z^3$ in the negative half of the complex plane. Now, consider the point $z_0 = 0$. Since $f$ is analytic, we know that there exists $r>0$ such that $f$ can be expressed as a power series on the set $D(0,r)$. For $\Re(z) > 0$, we find that $f(z) = z^3$ in the set $D(0,r)$. For $\Re(z) < 0$, we find that $f(z) = -z^3$ in the set $D(0,r)$. Since $z^3=-z^3$ in the disk $D(0, r)$, we have reached a contradiction. Therefore, the theorem is true. $QED$

Comment: How do you know that "$f(z)=z^3$ in the positive half of the complex plane"?

Comment: @arkeet The uniqueness theorem.

Comment: What does the uniqueness theorem state? If it's what I'm guessing, you can conclude directly from $f(s) = s^3$ on $S$ that $f(z) = z^3$ everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$, and obtain a contradiction more easily.

Comment: @arkeet "Suppose both $f$ and $g$ are analytic on $U$, and there is $S ⊂ U$ with an accumulation point in $U$ such that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z ∈ S$, then $f ≡ g$ in $U$."

Comment: @arkeet I think you are right. Thanks for the help; it makes it a much cleaner proof.

Comment: Yup, just take $U = \mathbb{C}$. It would be good to refer to the theorem in your proof.

Comment: @arkeet Done. I showed that $f(z) = z^3 = -z^3$ in all $\mathbb C$ instead. Again, thanks for the help.